# Why am I receiving a Null Reference Exception on button Clear event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Good day all. I have tried and failed to find an answer to a couple of errors I'm receiving with this small project I created. I have a master.masterpage and 3 other child pages (content). Each one has a different flavor of a form. All the others work fine. This particular content page is not giving me the results I want.

First, when I hit submit and there are no validation errors, I'd like the label populated with "Success!!". currently it does not display even though the fields are valid.

Second, I want to clear all textboxes with a clear button but receive the following error. "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code."

Can someone explain where I need corrections with good learning points?

Here is my asp.net code and  vb code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Page3.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

### Rental Car Application Sheet

```
<div id="button2">
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Clear" />
</div>
```

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Dim form1 As Control
Protected Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, ByVal f As System.EventArgs)
    If Page.IsValid Then
        Label11.Text = "Success!!"
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    For Each Control In form1.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is TextBox Then
            Control.Text = ""     'Clear all text
        End If
    Next Control
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Although I'd like to fix it, i'd rather understand why i'm getting the error.

Comment: Visit the link I provided, it will explain more in detail as to why... You are trying to use an object when it's either nothing or null...

Comment: Thanks! I'm reviewing the information.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict.  `Text` is not a member of Web.UI.Control, so that wont compile.  It is hard to tell what you mean to do with `Dim form1 As Control`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use me.controls instead of form1.controls.  Me.Controls will get the current control collection

```
For Each Control In Me.Controls
```